# Eclipse doesn't show correct tables in Hibernate config

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, configuration

I'm making a new project with Hibernate.
I have some problems configure hibernate correctly in my Eclipse environment.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
                                         "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory name="">
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">XXXXX</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://localhost/Framework</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">sa</property>
  <property name="hibernate.default_schema">Framework</property>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">10</property>
  <property name="show_sql">true</property>
 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

My Eclipse environment only sees the master database instead of my Framework database. Can someone help me with this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The database was not correctly configured. The user didn't have the correct permissions. After fixing this it works.